pass header value in the url of x-amazon-apigateway-integration URI
I would to like to construct the x-amazon-apigateway-integration URI based on the header value coming in.
For example, if header "initial" is "123" then I would like to construct my x-amazon-apigateway-integration URI as "/api/down-stream/path1/{pathvariable1}/node/123". if header "initial" is "345" then I would like to construct my x-amazon-apigateway-integration URI as "/api/down-stream/path1/{pathvariable1}/node/345".
I know I can pass the header value to my target URI by using
requestParameters:
  "integration.request.header.initial" : "method.request.header.initial"

but it is not properly constructing the URI as /api/down-stream/path1/value-of-path-var-1/node/345 instead in the logs it shows as /api/down-stream/path1/value-of-path-var-1/node/{initial}
